# Write *.sql file with FME

Tags: postgis, sql, fme-form

Is it possible to write sql files containing all the `CREATE TABLE...` and `INSERT...` statements etc. with FME instead of directly execute them against the database (here: PostGIS)?

Background is that I have a PostGIS DB on a remote server that I am not able to access with FME Workbench directly, but I can transfer i.e. textfiles (like *.sql) to it in order to build the databases.

Comment: Do you have a local server available?
Execute FME locally and enable the query log on this one. Or create all the tables locally and dump/restore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the documentation https://docs.safe.com/fme/2018.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_ReadersWriters/postgis/PostGIS_writer.htm and a question sent to user forum  https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/111277/can-i-create-pgdump-file-like-ogr2ogr.html FME does not have that option.

Use the GDAL ogr2ogr utility https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html with the pgdump driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pgdump.html instead or use a local PostGIS database as an intermediate target.

Comment: I should have mentioned that we unfortunately have to read from GE Smallworld datastores which are not covered by ogr2ogr. A locally accessible PostGIS instance as an intermediate target is for sure an option, best if we can automatize the pgdump.

Comment: Make a feature request for FME. FME uses already GDAL for some formats and SAFE sponsored the raster side of the GDAL GeoPackage driver.